# Exception on calling getAdapter()

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

`LinkAdapter` is a  class which extends the `ArrayAdapter`.

```
private static List<LinkData> linkDataList = new ArrayList<LinkData>();
private LinkAdapter la;
la = new LinkAdapter(someLinkDataitmes, getActivity()); 
ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.urls);
lv.setAdapter(la);


public class LinkData {
    private String name, image, description;

    public LinkData(String name, String image, String description){
        this.name = name;
        this.image=image;
        this.description=description;
        }
}
```

Now I later want to update my `listview`,

```
ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.urls);
LinkAdapter mListAdapter = ((LinkAdapter)lv.getAdapter()); // this line is giving an error.
mListAdapter.add(new LinkData(name_val, image_val, description_val));
mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But the code is not working(giving a `NullPointerException`)

Searched a lot on the internet, but could not find a specific answer to my problem.

Comment: Post a Logcat of the exception.

Comment: Why not use the "la" field that you are assigning when you initially set the adapter?

Comment: please post more code. your current code won't even compile. first block of code put in a method, and post logcat .

Comment: @dymmeh la is defined in a different class. Is there a way that I can do that.

Comment: @Prmths My application freezes badly after when I try to do this thing, so I am unable to capture logcat's output.

Answer (score 0):

You never added a Adapter to your ListView, as far as i can see. The Adapter does not comes embedded with your ListView by default, so you need to create it and add it.

If you do mListAdapter.setAdapter( YOUR_ARRAY_ADAPTER_GOES_HERE ); before you try to recover it, it should work properly.

The NPE is because you cannot do a "get" on a reference to something that was never there.

Comment: lv.setAdapter(la); I guess 5th line does the job ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I had the same problem and I saw through debugging that the method getAdapter() on the ListView returns a ListAdapter which can be casted into an HeaderViewListAdapter. Then on that adapter it is possible to call the method getWrappedAdapter() and the result can be casted on your CustomAdapter.

EDIT!
My need was to add a new item on the list after inserting it in the database.
I created a method on the activity that inserts my Item in the list.

```
private void addItem(Item item) {
  ListView lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myCustomListView);
  HeaderViewListAdapter adapter = (HeaderViewListAdapter) lstView.getAdapter();

  MyCustomAdapter customAdapter = (MyCustomAdapter) adapter.getWrappedAdapter();

  customAdapter.add(item);
  customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I call this method after I insert the Item in the database.